# AttributeError: 'ParquetFile' object has no attribute 'row_groups'

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow, fastparquet

Pythonistas!

Not sure what I am doing wrong while reading a `parquet` file here.

I have all the necessary packages installed - `pandas`, `fastparquet` & `pyarrow`

The code literally is reading the `parquet` file

```
import pandas as pd 

FILE = 'file://minute_equities_all/minute/A/AA.parquet'

pd = pd.read_parquet(FILE,engine='fastparquet')
```

This keeps giving me,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ppatel/opt/miniconda3/envs/quant/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parquet.py", line 493, in read_parquet
    return impl.read(
  File "/Users/ppatel/opt/miniconda3/envs/quant/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parquet.py", line 347, in read
    result = parquet_file.to_pandas(columns=columns, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ppatel/opt/miniconda3/envs/quant/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastparquet/api.py", line 722, in to_pandas
    rgs = filter_row_groups(self, filters) if filters else self.row_groups
AttributeError: 'ParquetFile' object has no attribute 'row_groups'
```

Changing the engine to `pyarrow` also doesn't help -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ppatel/Desktop/development/data-sync/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    pf = pd.read_parquet(FILE,engine='pyarrow')
  File "/Users/ppatel/opt/miniconda3/envs/quant/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parquet.py", line 493, in read_parquet
    return impl.read(
  File "/Users/ppatel/opt/miniconda3/envs/quant/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parquet.py", line 240, in read
    result = self.api.parquet.read_table(
  File "/Users/ppatel/opt/miniconda3/envs/quant/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/parquet/__init__.py", line 2737, in read_table
    dataset = _ParquetDatasetV2(
  File "/Users/ppatel/opt/miniconda3/envs/quant/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/parquet/__init__.py", line 2351, in __init__
    self._dataset = ds.dataset(path_or_paths, filesystem=filesystem,
  File "/Users/ppatel/opt/miniconda3/envs/quant/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/dataset.py", line 694, in dataset
    return _filesystem_dataset(source, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ppatel/opt/miniconda3/envs/quant/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/dataset.py", line 439, in _filesystem_dataset
    fs, paths_or_selector = _ensure_single_source(source, filesystem)
  File "/Users/ppatel/opt/miniconda3/envs/quant/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/dataset.py", line 415, in _ensure_single_source
    raise FileNotFoundError(path)
FileNotFoundError: /Users/ppatel/Desktop/development/data-sync/minute_equities_all/minute/A/AA.parquet
```

Am I missing something here? Any help will be appreciated!

Attaching an example file here (expires in 30 days) - https://easyupload.io/xsqhhw

Adding some details around package versions -

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
abseil-cpp                20211102.0           he49afe7_0    conda-forge
arrow-cpp                 8.0.0           py310h72c8010_0
aws-c-common              0.4.57               hb1e8313_1
aws-c-event-stream        0.1.6                h23ab428_5
aws-checksums             0.1.9                hb1e8313_0
aws-sdk-cpp               1.8.185              he271ece_0
beautifulsoup4            4.11.1          py310hecd8cb5_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
boost-cpp                 1.70.0               hd59e818_1    conda-forge
bottleneck                1.3.5           py310h4e76f89_0
brotli                    1.0.9                hca72f7f_7
brotli-bin                1.0.9                hca72f7f_7
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py310h1961e1f_1004    conda-forge
bs4                       4.11.1               hd3eb1b0_0
bzip2                     1.0.8                h1de35cc_0
c-ares                    1.18.1               h0d85af4_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2022.6.15.1          h033912b_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2022.6.15.1        pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.15.1          py310hc55c11b_0
charset-normalizer        2.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cramjam                   2.5.0           py310hcf052fe_0    conda-forge
cryptography              37.0.4          py310h52c3658_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                   py_1001    conda-forge
fastparquet               0.8.3           py310h936d966_0    conda-forge
fonttools                 4.25.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
freetype                  2.11.0               hd8bbffd_0
fsspec                    2022.8.2           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
gflags                    2.2.2             hb1e8313_1004    conda-forge
giflib                    5.2.1                haf1e3a3_0
glog                      0.5.0                h25b26a9_0    conda-forge
grpc-cpp                  1.46.1               h067a048_0
icu                       58.2              h0a44026_1000    conda-forge
idna                      3.3                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          hecd8cb5_3538
jpeg                      9e                   hca72f7f_0
kiwisolver                1.4.2           py310he9d5cce_0
krb5                      1.19.2               hcd88c3b_0
lcms2                     2.12                 hf1fd2bf_0
lerc                      3.0                  he9d5cce_0
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                hca72f7f_7
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                hca72f7f_7
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                hca72f7f_7
libcurl                   7.84.0               h6dfd666_0
libcxx                    12.0.0               h2f01273_0
libdeflate                1.8                  h9ed2024_5
libedit                   3.1.20210910         hca72f7f_0
libev                     4.33                 haf1e3a3_1    conda-forge
libevent                  2.1.10               h815e4d9_4    conda-forge
libffi                    3.3                  hb1e8313_2
libiconv                  1.17                 hac89ed1_0    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.46.0               ha29bfda_0
libpng                    1.6.37               ha441bb4_0
libprotobuf               3.20.1               h8346a28_0
libssh2                   1.10.0               h7535e13_3    conda-forge
libta-lib                 0.4.0                haf1e3a3_0    conda-forge
libthrift                 0.15.0               h054ceb0_0
libtiff                   4.4.0                h2ef1027_0
libwebp                   1.2.2                h56c3ce4_0
libwebp-base              1.2.2                hca72f7f_0
libxml2                   2.9.14               hbf8cd5e_0
libxslt                   1.1.35               h5b33f42_0
libzlib                   1.2.12               hfe4f2af_2    conda-forge
lxml                      4.9.1           py310h6c45266_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h23ab428_1
matplotlib                3.5.2           py310hecd8cb5_0
matplotlib-base           3.5.2           py310hfb0c5b7_0
mkl                       2021.4.0           hecd8cb5_637
mkl-service               2.4.0           py310hca72f7f_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.1           py310hf879493_0
mkl_random                1.2.2           py310hc081a56_0
multitasking              0.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
munkres                   1.1.4                      py_0
ncurses                   6.3                  hca72f7f_3
numexpr                   2.8.3           py310hdcd3fac_0
numpy                     1.23.1          py310hdcd3fac_0
numpy-base                1.23.1          py310hfd2de13_0
oandapyv20                0.7.2                    pypi_0    pypi
openpyxl                  3.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1q               hfe4f2af_0    conda-forge
orc                       1.7.4                h9274d09_0
packaging                 21.3               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pandas                    1.4.3           py310he9d5cce_0
pillow                    9.2.0           py310hde71d04_1
pip                       22.1.2          py310hecd8cb5_0
pyarrow                   8.0.0           py310h53e4f6e_0
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 22.0.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.0.9           py310hecd8cb5_0
pysocks                   1.7.1              pyha2e5f31_6    conda-forge
python                    3.10.4               hdfd78df_0
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python_abi                3.10                    2_cp310    conda-forge
pytz                      2022.1          py310hecd8cb5_0
re2                       2022.04.01           he9d5cce_0
readline                  8.1.2                hca72f7f_1
requests                  2.28.1             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
setuptools                63.4.1          py310hecd8cb5_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
snappy                    1.1.9                he9d5cce_0
soupsieve                 2.3.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sqlite                    3.39.2               h707629a_0
ta-lib                    0.4.19          py310h7f5fb2b_4    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               h5d9f67b_0
tornado                   6.2             py310hca72f7f_0
tzdata                    2022a                hda174b7_0
urllib3                   1.26.11            pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
utf8proc                  2.6.1                h9ed2024_0
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
xz                        5.2.5                hca72f7f_1
yfinance                  0.1.74             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.12               h4dc903c_2
zstd                      1.5.2                hcb37349_0
```

Comment: which versions of pandas, fastparquet and python are you using?

Comment: Hey @0x26res added some details above
- pandas 1.4.3
- fastparquet 0.8.3
- pyarrow 8.0.0

Comment: Have you tried with `engine='pyarrow'`?

Comment: That doesn't help also - with `engine = 'pyarrow'`. It seems it can't even locate the file

Comment: Instead of using `file://minute_equities_all/minute/A/AA.parquet`, can you try `pyarrow` with only the path, no `file://` prefix?

Comment: Hey @UweL.Korn still no luck ): `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'minute_equities_all/minute/A/AA.parquet'` this was without the `file://` prefix

Comment: Are you sure the file actually exists? Does `open(.., "b")` with the exact same path work?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, one of the causes of the issue appears to be dependent on incorrect file access path. Providing correct path solves it.

The other one seems to depend on mismatch between `pyarrow` and `fastparquet` load/save versions. This behavior however is not consistent (or I was not able to pin-point it across different versions) and depends on the version of the packages (very annoying). For example: at some point `save` had to occur with `pyarrow` and load with `fastparquet`. At some point, after package updates, both `load` and `save` started relying on the same version. Strange.

Additionally, I found there seems to be a GitHub issues that refers to the same issue, but different root-cause. Either way, if the path is correct, the update of the packages to "matching" versions should solve the issue.